# Nametag fiddle: matching data with its rules for display

Tags: javascript, typescript

The problem statement is as follows:
I have a database of name tag data. I want to display these name tags to the screen. Each item of information on a nametag has certain rules for its display.

Here I have encoded those rules for display into a function `nameTagConvertToDisplay` to show what I mean. This function is just a bunch of `if` statements, and I don't really like it. I feel like there is probably a class-based approach that is cleaner.

I'm not too concerned with the code inside the `renderNameTags` function because it's just boilerplate and not related to my actual problem. The function/class structure is really what I am looking for help on

https://jsfiddle.net/4ngzdxot/9/

```
interface NameTagDatum {
  name: string;
  job:  string;
  age: number;
}


let nameTagData = [
{name: "Joe", job: "QA Tester", age: 30},
{name: "Althea", job: "Senior Software Developer", age: 56}
]

function nameTagConvertToDisplay (nameTag, attribute) {
  if (attribute === "name") {
    return "My name is " + nameTag.name
  }
  if (attribute === "job") {
    return "My job is " + nameTag.job
  }
  if (attribute === "age") {
    if (nameTag.age > 40) {
        return "I am " + nameTag.age.toString() + " years young!"
    }
    else {
        return "I am " + nameTag.age.toString() + " years old"
    }
  }
}

function renderNameTags(nameTags: NameTagDatum[]) {
  let nameTagsToRender = []
  nameTags.forEach(nameTag => {
    let nameTagToRender = ""
  
    nameTagToRender += nameTagConvertToDisplay(nameTag, 'name') + "<br>"
    nameTagToRender += nameTagConvertToDisplay(nameTag, 'job') + "<br>"
    nameTagToRender += nameTagConvertToDisplay(nameTag, 'age') + "<br>"
    nameTagsToRender.push(nameTagToRender)
  })
  return nameTagsToRender.join("<br>")
}

document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = renderNameTags(nameTagData);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you are expected to create a function, but it seems unnecessary as framed.

````
interface NameTagDatum {
    name: string;
    job:  string;
    age: number;
}

let nameTagData = [
    {name: "Joe", job: "QA Tester", age: 30},
    {name: "Althea", job: "Senior Software Developer", age: 56}
]

function renderNameTags(nameTags: NameTagDatum[]): string {
    return nameTags.flatMap(nameTag => {
        return [
            `My name is ${nameTag.name}`,
            `My job is ${nameTag.job}`,
            `My age is ${nameTag.age} years ${nameTag.age > 40 ? 'old' : 'young!'}`
        ]
    }).join('<br>')
}

console.log(renderNameTags(nameTagData))
```
````